# Mac - Remove the Greater Than '>' From Git Terminal

Tags: git, macos, terminal, git-bash

I am new to this, anyways I was studying about `git` on my terminal, I wrote this statement to try to push a commit manually:

```
> git commit -m "commit this"
```

what I got was a `>` symbol on the next line, I tried exiting and going back to my pwd, nothing happened, it kept giving the `>` symbol on a new line when I hit enter. I tried `q` to quit nothing still happens. How do I get out of this without closing my terminal? I do use a mac btw.

Comment: git commit -m "commit this" is usually followed by file name(s) with relative path. Try and see if that works

Comment: You probably forgot one of the `"` and so your shell was waiting for you to close the quotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I tried exiting and going back to my pwd, nothing happened, it kept giving the > symbol on a new line when I hit enter. I tried q to quit nothing still happens. How do I get out of this without closing my terminal?

Type a `ctrl-D`, which is to say hold down the `control` key and type `D`. `ctrl-D` is the way you type an 'end of file' character.

I think what happened is that you left off the closing quote in your commit message, i.e. you did something like:

> git commit -m "commit this

Without the closing `"`, git will keep waiting for more input, which is why you get the `>` prompt. Typing and end-of-file character tells it that it's reached the end of the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Command (or Cmd) ⌘ and C` to exit.